# If every pair of points is contained in a connected subset, then the space is connected

Tags: general-topology

Suppose for each $a, b \in X$ there exists $A\subset X$ such that $A$ is connected and $a, b\in A$. How to show that $X$ is a connected space?

Comment: Suppose $X$ is not connected. Then there exist two sets ... pick $a$ in one and $b$ from the other...

Comment: If X is not connected A must be not connected we have a contradiction thats all ?

Comment: You should write things down more carefully than that, but that's the idea: the disconnection of X (say $X=U\cup V$) will lead to A being disconnected.

Comment: okay thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a continuous function $f:X\to\{0,1\}$. Given a pair of points $a,b\in X$, there is a connected subset $Y$ that contains both. Since $f\mid Y$ is continuous and $Y$ is connected, $f\mid Y$ is constant, so $f(a)=f(b)$. Since $a,b$ were arbitrary, $f$ is constant, so $X$ itself is connected.

Answer (score 1):

I will use the following Lemma, the proof of which I leave to you:
**Lemma:** If $\mathcal C$ is a collection of sets in $X$ with a non-empty intersection, i.e. $\bigcap \mathcal C\neq \varnothing$, then $\bigcup\mathcal C$ is connected.

---

**Theorem:** *If every pair of points is contained in a connected subset, then the space is connected.*

**Proof:** If $X = \varnothing$, it is trivially connected. Suppose $X\ne \varnothing$. Consider $a\in X$. For every $y\in X$, there exists a connected set $E_{ay}$ such that $a,y\in E_{ay}$. Note that $$X = \bigcup_{y\in X,y\ne a} E_{ay}$$ and $$\bigcap_{y\in X,y\ne a} E_{ay} = \{a\} \neq \varnothing$$ and so $X$ itself is connected. In the last step, I have used the preceding Lemma.